Aho-Corasick algorithm: possible to match non-adjacent keywords?
I need to match non-adjacent keywords in a large collection of texts. If there is a match it should return the match, else return "unknown". For the first trial run it will be several thousands texts files, later more. There are about 3,500 keyword sets. A keyword set can contain one word, two words or three words. So computing power and speed is important. Aho-Corasick seems a good choice. I have done a trial implementation (see below) when the keywords are written next to each other using the Python package pyahocorasick.
But how to accommodate non-adjacency with Aho-Corasick?
I saw there is one or two examples of raw code around how to create the necessary classes and implement the Aho-Corasick algorithm in Python, but wanted to get some advice here before I dive into this.
Previously done Regular Expressions (RegEx) string matching. Given the amount of keyword sets, it will take a lot (!) of time to enter them each manually and be error-prone. Also not sure how fast a RegEx solution will be with the amount of data. So that is why I headed for Aho-Corasick.
Code
import ahocorasick

# function to build trie / automaton
def build_keyword_trie(keywords):
    trie = ahocorasick.Automaton()
    for idx, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
        trie.add_word(keyword, (idx, keyword))
    trie.make_automaton()
    return trie

#Keyword list
keywords_list = ["apple pie", "banana bread", "quick brown fox"]

# function to match keywords
def match_keywords(text, keyword_trie):
    tempMa = []
    for end_index, (keyword_idx, keyword) in keyword_trie.iter(text):
        try: 
            start_index = end_index - len(keyword) + 1
            tempMa.append((start_index, end_index, keyword))
        except Exception as e:                      
            tempMa.append('unknown')
    
    return tempMa

# define function to run through lists of several text snippets  
def process_multiple_snippets(snippets, keywords):
    #build automaton
    keyword_trie = build_keyword_trie(keywords)
    match = []
    #loop through each text snippet in list
    for snippet_idx, text_to_search in enumerate(snippets, start=1):
        if  match_keywords(text_to_search, keyword_trie) != None:
            match.append( match_keywords(text_to_search, keyword_trie))
        
        else:             
            match.append('unknown')
    
    return match

#Sample texts
snippets_list = [
    "The quick brown fox loves apple pie.",
    "Another snippet with different keywords.",
    "The cat loves banana bread.",
    "The cat loves pie.",
    "The cat loves bread."]

#apply function
matches = process_multiple_snippets(snippets_list, keywords_list)

print(matches)

Output matches variable:
[[(4, 18, 'quick brown fox'), (26, 34, 'apple pie')], [], [(14, 25, 'banana bread')], [], []]

